# Multiple inheritance of cython cdef classes

Tags: python, cython, multiple-inheritance

I have some classes implemented as `cdef class` in cython. In client python code, I would like to compose the classes with multiple inheritance, but I'm getting a type error. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
In [1]: %load_ext cython

In [2]: %%cython
   ...: cdef class A:
   ...:     cdef int x
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.x = 0
   ...: cdef class B:
   ...:     cdef int y
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.y = 0
   ...: 

In [3]: class C(A, B):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-83ef5091d3a6> in <module>()
----> 1 class C(A, B):
      2     pass

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Is there any way to get around this?

The [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#subclassing) say that:

> A Python class can inherit from multiple extension types provided that the usual Python rules for multiple inheritance are followed (i.e. the C layouts of all the base classes must be compatible).

I'm trying to understand what this could possibly mean given the trivial example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty restricted. As best as I can tell all but one of the classes has to be empty. Empty classes can have `def` functions, but not `cdef` functions or `cdef` attributes.

Take a Cython class:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef int x
```

This translates to C code:

```
 struct __pyx_obj_2bc_A { // the name might be different
     PyObject_HEAD
     int x;
 };
```

Essentially just a C struct containing the basic Python object stuff, and an integer.
The restriction is that a derived class must contain only one `PyObject_HEAD` and that its `PyObject*` should also be interpretable as a `struct __pyx_obj_2bc_A*` or a `struct __pyx_obj_2bc_B*`.

In your case the two integers `x` and `y` would attempt to occupy the same memory (so conflict). However, if one of the types was empty then they would share the `PyObject_HEAD` but not conflict further.

`cdef` functions cause a `struct __pyx_vtabstruct_2bc_A *__pyx_vtab;` to be added to the struct (so it's not empty). This contains function pointers which allows inherited classes to override the `cdef` functions.

Having two `cdef` classes that inherit from a common third class is OK, event if the common third class is not empty.

```
cdef class A:
    cdef int x

cdef class B(A):
    cdef int y

cdef class C(A):
    pass

class D(B,C):
    pass
```

---

The internal Python code that does this check is the function [`best_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f735485acf2e35a75d2fa019feb8f905598c4e5/Objects/typeobject.c#L2007%60) if you really want to investigate the details of the algorithm.

---

With reference to "is there any way to get round this?" the answer is "not really." Your best option is probably composition rather than inheritance (i.e. have class `C` hold an `A` and `B` object, rather than inherit from `A` and `B`)